# BigQuery parse URL web address

Tags: sql, url, google-bigquery

I need help to parse out the web URL using BigQuery. Need to remove the string/text after last forward slash '/' and return the URL back. The input URL length can vary record by record. If the input URL does not have and string/text after domain address it should return the URL as it is.

Here are some examples.

**Input Web URL**

> https://www.stackoverflow.com
>
> https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions
>
> https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/some-text

**Expected Output**

> https://www.stackoverflow.com
>
> https://www.stackoverflow.com
>
> https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions
>
> https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

I have tried using SPLIT function which converts the URL string into ARRAY and calculate array size using ARRAY_LENGTH. However it doesn't cover the all the various scenario I have mentioned above.

Please advise how to tackle this? using Standard SQL in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple **REGEXP_REPLACE** for the last "/" and strings after that.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(url, r"([^/])/[^/]*$", "\\1")
FROM (SELECT 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' as url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions' as url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://www.stackoverflow.com' as url
)
```

**Note**: \\1 (first capture group) represent the character just before "/", we need to consider the character to avoid matching with "//".

Test Result:

> https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions
>
> https://www.stackoverflow.com
>
> https://www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Bravo! I new there were a better way, but missed that trick. Bravo!

Comment: Forgot to mention - instead of `"\\1"` - you can use `r"\1"`

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant -  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @kshaikh - Sure, consider also voting up helpful answers :o)

Answer (score 4):

I think a `case` expression helps fill in the blank:

```
select (case when url like '%//%/%' then regexp_replace(url, '/[^/]+$', '')
             else url
        end)
from (select 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' as url union all
      select 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions' as url union all
      select 'https://www.stackoverflow.com' as url
      ) x;
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT url, 
  REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(url, '//', '\\'), r'/[^/]+$', ''), '\\', '//')
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

you can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'https://www.stackoverflow.com' url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/some-text' 
)
SELECT url, 
  REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(url, '//', '\\'), r'/[^/]+$', ''), '\\', '//') value
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row url                                                 value    
1   https://www.stackoverflow.com                       https://www.stackoverflow.com    
2   https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions             https://www.stackoverflow.com    
3   https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask         https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions  
4   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/some-text   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide a JavaScript UDF solution. Not because it is better for this scenario but it is always your last hope when things' getting really complicated.

(Also, I want to point out that, double slashes could exist in url like: https://www.stackoverflow.com//questions//ask, to handle which you may need extra logic coded in JavaScript)

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  remove_last_part_from_url(url STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js AS """
  var last_slash = url.lastIndexOf('/');
  var first_double_slash = url.indexOf('//');
  if (first_double_slash != -1 
      && last_slash != -1 
      && last_slash != first_double_slash + 1) {
    return url.substr(0, last_slash);
  }
  return url;
  """ ;
SELECT remove_last_part_from_url(url)
FROM (SELECT 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' as url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions' as url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://www.stackoverflow.com//questions' as url UNION ALL -- double slash after https://
  SELECT 'https:/invalid_url' as url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://www.stackoverflow.com' as url
)
```